# TypeScript - the best approach for typing functions?

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript, and I have a question around annotating types of functions.

Looking at this simple example:

```
export const add = (num1: number, num2: number):number => {
  return num1 + num2;
};
```

This feels well typed to me. The arguments have a type and the function's return type is also annotated.

Now consider this, also valid syntax:

```
export const add2:(num1: number, num2: number) => number = (num1, num2) => {
  return num1 + num2;
};
```

We're typing the variable `add2` itself. Sure. My linter shuts up about missing return types in either.

I could even do both:

```
export const add3:(num1: number, num2: number) => number = (num1: number, num2: number):number => {
  return num1 + num2;
};
```

My question is - are there any advantages or disadvantages to doing approaches 1, 2 or 3 here? Is there a more idiomatic style amoung them?

Comment: KISS. Less code = less chance of typos and easier to read. `export const add = (num1: number, num2: number) => {` IMO

Comment: Other than the obvious? Haha.

Comment: add2 and add3 feel crazy to me!  I’m team add1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare new variable and assign it in the same statement there is no need to explicitly specify the type - it will be assumed automatically. So for the use cases in your question first option will be the most optimal.

If you need to declare a variable and assign a value(function) to it later - the cleaner way to do this is to use Interfaces.
Something along these lines:

```
interface AddFunc {
  (num1: number, num2:number): number;
}

let add: AddFunc;
add = (a: number, b: number): number => a + b;
add(1, 2);
```